# The "Nobody claps, one person claps, everyone claps" Phenomenon

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the word to describe the phenomenon where at first nobody has the intension to clap (after a performance, lecture, etc). But suddenly one person starts clapping loudly, breaking the silence, and there goes the applause! Everyone starts clapping!

Comment: Perhaps *catalysis* as a back formation (in this figurative context) from *catalyst*.

Comment: You could say _everyone [follows suit](http://www.onelook.com/?w=follow+suit&ls=a)_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*[Chain reaction](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/chain_reaction)* (“A series of events, each one causing the next”) is the now-somewhat-cliched term often used for that  phenomenon.

Some slightly-less-relevant terms include *[nucleation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nucleation)*, *[trigger](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/trigger#Noun)*, *[seed](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/seed#Noun)* (senses 5 or 6), *[goad](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/goad#Verb)*, *[stimulus](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stimulus#Noun)*, and aforementioned *[catalysis](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/catalysis#Noun)*.